# Find maximum number of subsets.

Tags: combinatorics

> Let,  $S=\{1,2,3,...,n\}.$
>   $T=\{s_i \subset S : |s_i|=m; |s_i \cap s_j| \leq k,  \forall i\neq j\}$
>           Let, maximum possible cardinality of $T=f(n, m, k) $. Find $f(n, m, k) $.

Answer (score 0):

Given $|s_i| = m$, we can say that the ways we can have $s_i = n \; \textbf{C} \; m$. Now assuming $k$ ranges from 0 to m,

For $k=m$ (no common element), 
$$T(n, m, m) = n\;\textbf{C} \;2m $$

For $k=m-1$ (1 common element), 
$$T(n, m, m-1) = (n\;\textbf{C} \;2m-2) ((n-2m-2)\;\textbf{C}\;1) $$

For $k=m-2$ (2 common elements), 
$$T(n, m, m-2) = (n\;\textbf{C} \;2m-4) ((n-2m-4)\;\textbf{C}\;2) $$

Hence, $$T = \sum_{k=0}^{m} (n\;\textbf{C} \;2(m-(m-k)))\left((n-2(m-(m-k))) \; \textbf{C}\; (m-k) \right)$$